# Python Code to Decode Special Character Encodings Like "‚Äú"?

Tags: python, character-encoding

I have some strings with character encodings, e.g.:

> designated building areas as **‚Äúsensitive‚Äù**
>
> suitability for the **company‚Äôs** needs?
>
> **organization‚Äôs** enterprise architecture?

I've Googled quite a bit but I haven't yet found the correct way to address this.

What's the correct way to translate these codes to UTF-8 in Python?

Comment: That is not character encodings. That is corrupted text. Wherever you got it from, the wrong encoding was used, and thus the text is corrupted.

Comment: Wow. My .csv file has `“sensitive”` but when I open it with Excel it comes in as `‚Äúsensitive‚Äù`.

Comment: Sorry, you are not providing enough information. What do you mean by .csv file? Plaintext? LibreOffice? Some other software? Is Excel giving you any errors? Please do not be vague when describing a problem.

Comment: I have a .csv file, i.e. a standard comma-separated-values format file, that was provided to me and all the encoding is fine. It is a UTF-8 file. When I open the file in BBEdit, I see, for example, `“sensitive”`.  When I open that same file in Excel and examine same text, I see the corrupted text, `‚Äúsensitive‚Äù`.

Comment: @hotvector Your comment steered me in the right direction. If you would like to post it as an answer I will mark it as accepted. :)